# Tour of Go exercise #2: For continued

Tags: go

This may be a simple thing I can't see for some reason but I am going through the Go Tour and in the `For continued` section and I was wondering if someone could explain to me how the logic executes and delivers the statement to be `1024`.

https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/2

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    sum := 1
    for ; sum < 1000; {
        sum += sum
    }
    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its really just doing powers of 2

so the outputs are

1 2 4 8 16 32 ... 1024

Think of this loop as

```
sum = 1
while(sum < x) {
    sum = sum * 2
}
```